# Ĉu oni elparolas la sufikson '-ĉjo' malsame ol 'ĉo'?

Tags: pronunciation

Ĉu la vira karesforma sufikso '-ĉjo' efektive havas malsaman prononcon ol 'ĉo'? Se jes, kio estas la diferenco?

Comment: Estus bone, se oni farus elŝuteblajn sondosierojn kun la du sonojn. Bedaŭrinde mia loĝeja estas tro brua.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En rapida parolo oni ne klare distingas "ĉo" de "ĉjo". Sed fakte ili estas malsamaj. En "ĉo", la voĉkordoj vibras nur dum la elparolado de "o". En "ĉjo", la voĉkordoj vibras dum la elparolado de "j" kaj "o".

La voĉkordoj ne vibras (senvoĉa):

- Ĉ - [ekfrota gingiva senvoĉa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_palato-alveolar_affricate) - [t͡ʃ]

La voĉkordoj vibras (voĉa):

- J - duonvokalo [malvasta antaŭa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_front_unrounded_vowel) aŭ [palatala alproksimanto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatal_approximant) - [j] aŭ [ i̯ ](ili estas la samaj en Esperanto)
- O - [mezvasta malantaŭa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_back_rounded_vowel) - [o]

Vidu pli en [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/elparolo/bazaj_reguloj.html) kaj sonajn ekzemplojn en la [respondo de makis](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/708/36)

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK they are pronounced differently. In rough phonetic transliteration: /tSIo/ (unvoiced alveolar fricative, followed by a short and open [I] (JC Wells calls it "gliding non-syllabic"), followed by a closed [o]) vs /tSo/ (the same, but without the [I] sound).

Laŭ mi oni prononcas ilin malsame. Sufikso *-ĉjo* estas /tSIo/, ĝi enhavas mallongan kaj malferman [I] sonon. Sed *-ĉo* estas nur /tSo/, sen tiu sono.

Comment: La demando estas en Esperanto. Do eble la respondo devus esti en Esperanto. Tamen via respondo estas bona.

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev Pardonu min, mia Esperanto ne estas tro bone.

Comment: Is your transliteration representing the letter ‘c’ instead of ‘ĉ’? Or is the /tS/ supposed to be /t͡ʃ/

Comment: @NeilRoberts The latter. "c" would be /ts/. I'm using SAMPA (http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/sampa/index.html) for the transliteration.

Comment: Isn't *j* pronounced /j/, not /I/?

Comment: @Max Not really. In a closer phonetic transcription you could probably make a case for /tSIjo/, but the /j/ sound itself is IMHO not 'vocalic' enough to be fit between /tS/ and /o/

Comment: Why should it be "vocalic"? My very point is that *j* is a semi-vowel but your transcription treats it as a full syllabic vowel.

Comment: My argument is that it is a full vowel in this position.

Comment: That's your assertion, but you haven't really made any argument for it. It may be that *you* pronounce it that way, but that's no evidence that it's common or correct. It disagrees with [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/elparolo/bazaj_reguloj.html#j). Moreover, if it were a vowel, then it should take stress, but it does not.

Comment: Kiel transskribo povus helpi la demandanton se la Esperanta skribo jam estas sufiĉe preciza? Vi nur ŝanĝis la signojn, kaj ŝajnas ke tiuj signoj ne estas tre konataj laŭ la aliaj komentoj.

Answer (score 4):

Tute malsamaj ili estas. Ĉiu litero estas prononcata en Esperanto.

(Klaku la vorton por aŭdi ĝin)

- [paĉjo](http://forvo.com/word/pa%C4%89jo/#eo) -- pat͡ʃjo (ne pat͡ʃ**i**jo)
- [voĉo](http://forvo.com/word/vo%C4%89o/#eo) -- vot͡ʃo
- [sandviĉo](http://forvo.com/word/sandvi%C4%89o/#eo) -- sandvit͡ʃo

Comment: Tute malsamaj, ĉu?  Evidente miaj oreloj ankoraŭ ne estas sufiĉe trejnitaj al Esperanto - kiam oni alparolas mian amikon Anĉjo, ja ŝajnas al mi ke ili nomas lin anĉo! Fakte mi kredas ke tre malmultaj lingvoj efektive distingas inter /tʃ/ kaj /tʃj/.

Comment: @jzknuckles Eble "tute" estas troigo. :P Tamen, ili ja estas malsamaj. Jen, pere de forvo: [paĉjo](http://forvo.com/word/pa%C4%89jo/#eo) kaj [sandviĉo](http://forvo.com/word/sandvi%C4%89o/#eo)

Comment: En rapida parolo oni ne klare distingas "ĉo" de "ĉjo". Sed fakte ili estas malsamaj. En "ĉo", la voĉkordoj vibras nur dum la elparolado de "o". En "ĉjo", la voĉkordoj vibras dum la elparolado de "j" kaj "o". [PMEG - Bazaj elparolaj reguloj](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/elparolo/bazaj_reguloj.html)

Comment: @Marco Vi devintus afiŝi tion kiel respondon anstataŭ nur komenton, tio estas precize kion mi serĉis! Dankon!

Answer (score 3):

Because every letter in Esperanto has a single sound associated with it, there will never be a phonetically arbitrary spelling difference. In this case, the Jo makes the suffix sound like [ch-ee-ó] as opposed to  [ch-ó]

Laŭ la Esperanta sonsistemo, ĉiu litero havas nur unu sonon, do iam ajn ekzistas diferencan manieron de ortografio, ankaŭ ekzistos diferencan manieron de prononco

Mi esperas, ke tiu helpis vin  :)

Answer (score 3):

Ili estas malsamaj, kaj la malsameco estas precize kiel skribite: *j* elparoliĝis tute same kiel en aliaj vortoj. *Paĉjo* elparoliĝis kiel *paĉ* antaŭ *jo*.

They are different, and the difference is exactly as written: *j* makes the same (semivowel) sound here as it does in other contexts. *Paĉjo* is pronounced like *paĉ* followed by *jo*